# ERROR: Failed building wheel for skranger

Tags: windows, anaconda, setuptools, python-3.8

I am trying to install the package skranger using `pip install skranger`. However, I get an error **ERROR: Could not build wheels for skranger, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.**

In the traceback, I also see an error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'.** However, setuptools is already installed.

I have tried related solutions already on stackoverflow, but have yet to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you on Windows ? mybe this thread could help you https://github.com/crflynn/skranger/issues/53

Comment: Yes, I am on windows. Looks like the package is not compatible with windows. Thanks for the help!